# "invalid login" when attempting to update Joomla 3.4.8 to 3.7.5

Tags: upgrade

At `/administrator/index.php?option=com_joomlaupdate` I click `Install the update` to update from `3.4.8` to `3.7.5`, but immediately after clicking that button I receive a browser popup window `invalid login`.

I am logged into Joomla okay with a `super user` account, and the database user has full rights to the database.

After I click OK to the `invalid login` message, I am taken to the update screen where nothing happens.

If I visit Extensions > Manage > Install, and try and upload `Joomla_3.5.1-Stable-Full_Package` the screen will refresh and nothing happens.

If I unzip `Joomla_3.5.1-Stable-Full_Package` into the site's directory, and refresh admin (after deleting the installation folder), I get a pile of errors at `Extensions > Manage > Database > Fix`.

Help appreciated.

Comment: When you say *super user* you mean as *admin* in terms of Joomla admin, right ? Did you try to download the upgrade and then install it ? I mean using the Joomla interface, not unziping it in the site's dir ?

Comment: @jcm69, yes I mean as an _admin_. I did try using the Joomla interface @ `/administrator/index.php?option=com_joomlaupdate` - I click `Install the update` which is when I receive the error.

Comment: Did you try with a fresh 3.4.8 to see if the problem comes from the OS...

Comment: Hi @jcm69, I changed `configuration.php` to use the MySQL `root` user and the issue no longer remains. So the problem is caused by buggy permissions for the local user I created. This problem won't exist on the remote server.

Comment: @jcm69: add an answer and I'll select it.

Comment: I've tried to be more precise in the answer. Don't hesitate to edit or tell me what to change. Happy it worked for you ;)

Comment: Same issue for 3.7.5->3.8.1. Changing the database user to root doesn't help.

Comment: Same error on freshly installed Joomla 3.7.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that [you can not update directly](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/tag/3.6.5) from Joomla! lower than 3.6.5 (3.0.0 to 3.6.4 inclusive) to Joomla! 3.6.5 or later using the extensions manager. You need to use Joomla! Update or perform a manual update.

I assume you cannot use Joomla! Update if you are asking this question. Presumably your server is firewalled and cannot download the update directly. Therefore you need to follow Method **C** in [the Joomla! documentation on core updates](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Upgrading_from_Joomla_3.4.x_to_3.5).

Do note that later versions of Joomla! Update include their own upload and install for Joomla! core updates (I contributed that feature). Upgrading to the next Joomla! versions will be possible from Joomla! Update even if it cannot download the update package directly. There will be a second tab at the top of its page which allows you to use an upload & install method.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install a fresh 3.4.8 on **the same machine, same place, keep all things equal**.
If this doesn't work, there's a problem with your server and Joomla should tell you something about the problem (too old versions of PHP or MySQL, bad permissions etc.)
If it works do the update.
If it works :
1/ you can try to search for differences between the 2 installations. On Linux :

```
diff -r <<old_installation>> <<fresh_installation>>
```

you should find something...
NB : if you use many plugins, extensions etc. it's gonna be more complicated. You will have to install all of them before the *diff -r*. May be you'll find the one that causes the problem during this installations...
 **but** :
2/ You've got an installation which is OK: the fresh one ! You just have to modify the section of *configuration.php* concerning MySQL (DB name, username and password). Since you just updated it, why not trying... If it doesn't work, try to fix the DB : Extensions -> Manage -> Database, *Fix* button. If it doesn't work, do the same on a fresh 3.4.8 and update.
**If on different machines**, you may need :

```
mysqldump -u root -p<<password>> --opt <<old_DB>> > temp.sql
```

to dump the DB from one machine and

```
 mysql -u root -p<<password>> <<new_DB>> < temp.sql
```

to create it on the new machine.
Don't forget the command :

```
chown -R www-data:www-data <<Joomla_dir>>
```

when you modify files here and there ;)